# How to pass item from cart for place order function in Swiftui

Tags: swiftui

I have project that is Cash Register.  I have an issue in placeOrder function on how to submit to network via http post request.

What I expect: able to placeOrder all item in the cart

[image: Cart]

My cart view

```
    import SwiftUI

    struct CartContainer: View {

      @EnvironmentObject var order: OrderViewModel
      @ObservedObject private var orderviewmodel = OrderViewModel()
      @State private var showingModal = false

      var body: some View{
        ZStack{
         Color("lightGrayColor")
         .ignoresSafeArea()
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Text("Item Name")
                        .font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                        .frame(width:200)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Qty.").font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                        .padding(.leading, -78)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("Subtotal.").font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                        .padding(.leading, -78)
                    
                }
            }
            .padding(.top, 10)
 
            ScrollView{
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    TextField("customer", text: self.$order.customer)
                    ForEach(order.orderItems, id:\.id){ list in
                        HStack{
                             Text(list.product_name)
                                     .font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                                     .frame(width:200)
                                 Spacer()
                             Text("\(list.quantity)").font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                                     .padding(.leading, -78)
                            Spacer()
                            Text("\(list.price, specifier: "%.2f")").font(Font.system(size: 16, weight: .light))
                                     .padding(.leading, -78)
                       }
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                    }
                }.padding()
            }.padding()
       
            
            HStack{
                Text("Grand Total: ₱")
                Text(String(order.orderItems.map{$0.price}.reduce(0, +)))
            }
           
            .font(Font.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
                .padding(.bottom, 30)
                .padding(.leading, 40)
            Button(action: {
                self.order.placeOrder()
            }) {
                           Text("Charge")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .font(Font.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .padding(.top, 35)
                            .padding(.bottom, 35)
                            .background(Color("ButtonGreen"))
            }.padding(.bottom, -10)
        }
    }
    .frame(width: 550)
}
```

Order View Model for Add to Cart and PlaceOrder

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class OrderViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var orderItems = [Cart]()
@Published var isValid: Bool = false
var customer: String = "sample customer name"

func AddToCart(item: item) {
    
       let str:String = item.price
       let num = (str as NSString).floatValue
        
       if let ndx = orderItems.firstIndex(where: {$0.product_name == item.product_name}) {
           // already have this cart/item, UPDATE product row
            orderItems[ndx].quantity = orderItems[ndx].quantity + 1
            orderItems[ndx].price = orderItems[ndx].price + num
       } else {
           // add a new cart/item
        if item.quantity != "0.0"{
            orderItems.append(Cart(product_name: item.product_name, price:num, quantity: 1))
        }else{
            self.isValid = true
        }
      }
}
```

This PlaceOrder func will be the responsible data to be  submitted to network via http post.
productID and quantity value I added as a sample dummy value which working. but what I need is the value added in cart.

```
func placeOrder() {
     // im using jsonwebtoken to check if user is loggedin
     let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard let token = defaults.string(forKey:"jsonwebtoken") else{
        return
     }
    // dummy productID and Quantity value
    let order = Order(customer: self.customer, orderDetailsAttributes: 
        [OrderDetailsAttribute(productID: 2, quantity: 2)])
        // passing to web services (order) currently working
        Webservice().createPlaceOrder(token: token, order: order) { _ in
      }
    }
 }

 struct Cart: Identifiable{

   var id = UUID()
   var product_name: String
   var price: Float
   var quantity: Int
}
```

Hoping someone can direct me or help me i this code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the "placeOrder()" function is in OrderViewModel class.
So to send an order with the values in the carts, you could do something like this:

```
func placeOrder() {
     // im using jsonwebtoken to check if user is loggedin
     let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard let token = defaults.string(forKey:"jsonwebtoken") else {  // <-- not a good idea, use keychain
        return
     }
    // setup your order details, from the carts
    var orderDetails = [OrderDetailsAttribute]()
    for cart in orderItems {
        orderDetails.append(OrderDetailsAttribute(productID: cart.id, quantity: cart.quantity)
    }
    // don't send an order if there is no order to send
    if !orderDetails.isEmpty {
       let order = Order(customer: self.customer, orderDetailsAttributes: orderDetails) // <-- here
           // passing to web services (order) currently working
           Webservice().createPlaceOrder(token: token, order: order) { _ in }
    }

 }
```

Comment: thanks once again. I learn a lot. Through this example I be able to understand in real life swiftui coding problems. Your help and suggestions help me to research understand more.  Hope you continue help more! more power to you! and to all people here! thanks!